# Is there a quick way to use "remote trigger" drive mode on the Nikon D7100?

Tags: nikon, dslr, nikon-d7000, remote, nikon-d7100

With the announcement of the D7200, I've considered upgrading my old D7000. One thing I love about the D7000 is the option to change the drive mode using a dial underneath the mode dial. In particular, I still make use of the "remote trigger" drive mode.

However, this mode has been removed from the dial of the D7100/D7200; is there any quick way to access it on the D7100 without having to menu dive?

Comment: Voting to close - any answer we could provide would be based on supposition if not outright guesswork.

Comment: Agree, pure speculation.  You can add it to My Menu with other often-used menu items and activate it with DOF preview or Fn button?

Comment: I've tried to tweak the question from "why was it removed" to "what can I do about it?" With that, I think this becomes a reasonable question even if the answer turns out to be "nothing".

Comment: I assumed that there was a specific reason that Nikon did this. i.e. Because the D7100 doesn't have remote trigger functionality or because of some other technical reason. Removing the functionality without such would be non-sensical.